# Blackberry compatibility issue

Tags: blackberry, compatibility

i developed a simple uiapplication on 4.2.1 with a screen...if i compile it using 4.2.1 and run on 9500 simulator it goes to compatibility mode...i don't want this so this is what i tried.....edited the jad file added

RIM-TouchCompatibilityMode: false

RIM-TouchCompatibilityMode-UserChangeable: true

added the jad file to the project and compiled to create a new cod file...
cleaned the 4.7 (9500) simulator ...then loaded the application to simulator
File -> Load java program - > helloworld.cod

then ran the program...still compatibility mode....what am i doing wrong here...please let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way that i found for simulating OTA is by simulating SD card...copying the jad and cod files on the SD card then installing the app by running the jad file...it works...

Answer (score 1):

When you load an app into the simulator it just loads the bytes from the COD file and does not look at the JAD - so it doesn't see the configuration in the JAD.  A couple of ways around this would be:

1. Put your JAD/COD files on a webserver and install it from the simulator's browser, or
2. Create a build with the 4.7 or higher JDE